# Prevent nginx fill download bandwidth when work as reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

## What I do :

I'm using nginx for reverse proxy for access to cloud bucket/workers large contents (+1GB files).

## Problem is:

When 1 **client try to download a file** via this reverse proxy, **my nginx server download bandwidth fill to it's 1Gbps** even when clients maximum download speed is under 10 Mbps.

It seems that nginx try to download the complete large file then serve to clients.

## How to ?

Decrease nginx download speed to exactly/near my clients speed.

> For example : if 10 people download from nginx with a total of 500Mbps , nginx server download bandwidth increase to same/near 500Mbps and NOT fill to it's maximum bandwidth.

**Here is the reverse/proxy server config:**

```
server {
    server_name  my.domain.com;
    root /var/www/html/;
    set $bucket "123456.workers.com";
    sendfile on;
      
    location / {
        resolver 1.1.1.1;

        proxy_http_version     1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header       Connection "";
        proxy_set_header       Authorization '';
        proxy_set_header       Host $bucket;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
        proxy_set_header       X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header       X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_hide_header      cf-ray;
        proxy_hide_header      Content-Disposition;
        proxy_hide_header      report-to;
        proxy_hide_header      server;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-id-2;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-request-id;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-meta-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      x-amz-server-side-encryption;
        proxy_hide_header      Set-Cookie;
        proxy_ignore_headers   Set-Cookie;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        add_header             Cache-Control max-age=31536000;
        proxy_pass             https://$bucket; # without trailing slash
    }
      
    listen 80 default_server;
}
```

**Nginx Config :**

```
thread_pool default threads=384;
worker_processes auto; #some last versions calculate it automatically
worker_rlimit_nofile 20000;
user www-data;

pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 10000;
    multi_accept on;
}

http {
    fastcgi_read_timeout 900;
    aio threads=default;
    # cache informations about FDs, frequently accessed files
    # can boost performance, but you need to test those values
    open_file_cache max=150000 inactive=20s;
    open_file_cache_valid 30s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors on;
    
    access_log off;
    sendfile on;
    sendfile_max_chunk 512k;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;

    send_timeout 280;
    keepalive_requests 6000;

    server_tokens off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```